# Show custom windows using visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am creating new visual studio 2012 extension, I have made a menu command where I want it to show a custom window when i click on it, I am using C++ but I don't know how to trigger the window to show up, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

solved it by calling

```
void OnMyCommand(CommandHandler* /*pSender*/, DWORD /*flags*/, VARIANT* /*pIn*/, VARIANT* /*pOut*/)
{
    m_MyToolWindow.CreateAndShow();
}
```